# Custom hoverinfo box for plotly boxplot

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

Is there a way to add custom hoverinfo to plotly boxplot similar to how we can do it with bar plot using "text"?

Here is how we can add a custom text for bar plot type:

```
     plot_ly(
            x = ~var1, 
            y = ~output1, 
            color = ~var2, 
            colors = "add some color options", 
            type = "bar",
            hoverinfo = 'text',
            text = ~paste(paste0("Pathogen name: ",as.character(p.name)),
                          '</br></br>', paste0("Species/strain: 
                          ",as.character(ss.name)),
                          '</br>', paste0("Average prevalence: 
                          ",round(mean.prevalence,2)," (%)"),
                          '</br>', paste0("No. samples: ",no.observations)
                          ))
```

I'm not interested in a solution involving ggplot and ggplotly. I need to use plotly directly because ggplotly function causes issues when used within the subplot function inside a shiny app to create a view of multiple figures placed together.

The current hoverinfo for boxplot in plotly is quite messy and shows tons of different statistics at different places (e.g., median, 1st, 3rd quartiles, etc), but im trying to control what is shown inside a single concise box for each whisker with custom information. That box should be shown when the pointer hovers over any place related to that whisker if it makes sense...

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to customize hover text for plotly boxplots in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49495472/how-to-customize-hover-text-for-plotly-boxplots-in-r)

Comment: I dont think that example is directly relevant. In that example, it's tried to show a hover for outlier points and not necessarily the whisker. I tried to dig in to see if I can edit the code to simply show selected whisker statistics (e.g., level, mean, median, selected quantiles, etc.) when you point at each variable level on x axis but wasnt able to do so due to lack of proper code documentation. I was confused what's happening in the code... Any suggestion?